# Excel-like data grid editor with import/export functionality

Tags: java, excel, web-applications

I need to import data from excel file and present it on the web application. Next the presented data on the web should be able to edit by the user and exported to the excel file again. So I want to implement web application with possibilities to:

1. import Excel file
2. view Excel file in some way (table with simple a'la excel functionality: change cell type (radiobutton, checkbox, select, etc) or color, change column order/count, sorting, filtering, etc..., formula would be a plus)
3. change data presented in web app
4. export data to Excel file

What tools/libraries you can suggest me to use to accomplish above requirements?

I am planning to use for Spring 3/MVC (backend) & JSP (frontend) on JBoss 5/6 (app server).

### My Research:

I've done some research but want ask you also because i didn't find satisfactory results.

**For view and edit excel-like directly on the website:**

1. handsontable: http://handsontable.com
2. jquery.shit: http://jquerysheet.googlecode.com/svn/branches/3.x/jquery.sheet.html
3. jqgrid: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

What do you think about above propositions? There is something better? JQuery.shit is perfect but is not free, I need something free. Do you know something similar?

**For import/export Excel file** I found:

1. Java Excel API
2. Apache POI

Which is better, faster to learn or have better support? What else you can recommend?

Do you know is there maybe one common technology with those two important form me features: `'View and edit excel file on the web'` and `'import/export excel file'`?

Please advise me in this subject. I do not want to make a mistake before I start implementation.

Comment: jquery.sheet looks free to me. You only have to pay if you want support.